# Problem with GDAL distribution and netCDF support

Tags: gdal, c#, netcdf, gdalinfo

I have a problem with a GDAL distribution downloaded from http://www.gisinternals.com. It is the "release-1800-x64-gdal-2-2-1-mapserver-7-0-6.zip", downloaded just today.

In the information about this distribution it is indicated that it includes support for netCDF format.
But when I run "gdalinfo --formats", netCDF  is not in the list of the supported formats. Moreover, when trying to open a netCDF file from a C# program that uses the gdal/csharp libraries of this distribution, it says  that it doesn't recognizes the format. Same thing when using gdalinfo passing a netcdf file (checked as correct with another program) as parameter.

If this is a problem of the distribution, where can I find a distribution of GDAL binaries with full support (netCDF, HDF...) and with the libraries for C#?

Comment: For the development version http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1800-x64-gdal-mapserver.zip ogrinfo --formats and gdalinfo --formats show `netCDF -raster,vector- (rw+s): Network Common Data Format`

Comment: Have you looked into OSGEO4W? BTW I just downloaded the version you quoted, and it **has** netCDF listed. Maybe you need to sort the list?

Comment: Are you entirely sure you have the NetCDF libraries correctly installed and that they were detected during installation / compilation?

Comment: @AF7 the expanded zip file contains everything needed to run GDAL inside the SDKShell, so no chance to install a library incorrect, no installation or compiling necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The maintainer gisinternal site (Tamas Szekeres) answered me and solved the problem. I just had to run SDKShell.bat on the command prompt before using gdalinfo or other gdal apps.

I did exactly what I regularly reproach to other people: "you didn't read instructions!". Well, I hope this may at least be useful for other people that made the same mistake.

Comment: As you can see, I "solved" the problem...Thanks @user30184 for your interest. Really sorry for making you wasting time.

Comment: As you can see, I "solved" the problem...Thanks @AndreJ for your interest. Really sorry for making you wasting time.

Comment: As you can see, I "solved" the problem...Thanks @AF7 for your interest. Really sorry for making you wasting time.